# File Upload Progress Bar with Multiple and Different Inputs(MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I searched the internet and found this JavaScript and jQuery template for a file upload progress bar that works 100% fine(given the fact that you only use one form input).

My situation is that I need to pass one file and 4 other inputs like text and select to a Controller Action. The action works fine. My problem is to pass all these values through ajax to the Action whilst maintaining the progress bar functionality.

***Action Parameters***

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add_Attachment_to_Process(int id, int Department_id, HttpPostedFileBase Attachment, string sel_checkTask, string cbx_checkTask = null)
```

***HTML***

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/Processes/Add_Attachment_to_Process" id="myform">
    <input type="file" id="media" name="file" />


    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">
                <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" id="cbx_checkTask" name="cbx_checkTask">
                <span id="span_checkTask">Link Task</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <select class="form-control" id="sel_checkTask" name="sel_checkTask" style="width : 700px;" disabled>
            @foreach (var t in Model.User_Tasks)
            {
                <option value="@t.Task_Discription">@t.Task_Discription - @t.Key_Terms</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>

    <input id="id" name="id" value="@ViewBag.process_id " />
    <input id="Department_id" name="Department_id" value="@ViewBag.Department_id" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<div class="progress" style="width:40%">
    <div id="uploadprogressbar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">
        0%
    </div>
</div>
```

***JavaScript***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myform").on('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var formData = new FormData($("#myform")[0]);

            $.ajax({
                xhr: function () {
                    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {

                        if (e.lengthComputable) {

                            console.log('Bytes Loaded: ' + e.loaded);
                            console.log('Total Size: ' + e.total);
                            console.log('Percentage Uploaded: ' + ((e.loaded / e.total) * 100) + '%');

                            var percent = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);

                            $("#uploadprogressbar").html(percent + '%');
                            $("#uploadprogressbar").width(percent + '%');
                        }

                    });
                    return xhr;
                },
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Processes/Add_Attachment_to_Process',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function () {
                    alert('File Uploaded');
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText;
                    alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: When I use multiple inputs, the progress bar works, but the action is not called.

Comment: what is the result of 'formData'? Are you using .net core?

Comment: No I am not using core.Please advise how to get the result of 'formData'.

Comment: add 'console.log(formData )' below  'var formData = new FormData($("#myform")[0]);'

Comment: Thank you, i will do that.
Just realized that the Action is being called(sorry for that), but only 'id' and 'Department_id' are passed through, the rest of the parameters are null when the actionresult runs.

Comment: The length of 'formData' is 0. Does that mean anything?

Comment: I usual set the form values explicitly, I will add an answer how I do it. fommData with 0 length can mean that the form has no values, its hard to tell without seeing the debugging

Comment: I made a rookie mistake. the name of the file input did not match the name of the httppostedfilebase parameter. So the action sees the parameter as null. I have an if statement in the action that checks if the file parameter is null or contentlength of 0, then runs the code in the if statement if these arguements are false. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AS per the discussion above, try this sort of pattern to better see what values are not being sent

```
let f = new FormData();
    f.append('id', getYouFormValue("id"));
    f.append('sel_checkTask', getYouFormValue("sel_checkTask"));
    f.append('cbx_checkTask ', getYouFormValue("cbx_checkTask "));
    if (form.File) {
        f.append('File', getYouFormValue("file"));
    }
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: f
    }

    return fetch(`/Processes/Add_Attachment_to_Process`, requestOptions)
        .then(handleResponse)
        .then(result => {
           //do stuff
        });

function handleResponse(response) {
    return response.text().then(text => {
        const data = text && JSON.parse(text);
        if (!response.ok) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                console.log('not logged in')
            }
            const error = (data && data.message) || data.title || response.statusText;
            return Promise.reject(error);

        }
        return data;
    });
}

function getYouFormValue(element){
    let val  = document.getElementById(element);
    if(!val){
        console.log('empty value');
        return null;
    }

    return val;
```

}

Comment: Wow that's amazing, thank you. One question: Is the getYouFormValue() an existing function or was it user created?

Comment: In my application a pass an object into the submit function which I call in the place of that, but you are handling the submit event and thus you would have to create a function to get the form values out of your form.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will definitely consider the above JavaScript code in the next situation. Seems like renaming the file input to the correct name solved the problem.

Comment: @JohannesKarsten No problem, consider upvoting the answer if it was helpful please

Comment: I will accept this answer as the answer that solved the problem as I am not at a high enough level to upvote yet.